# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier()

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv, qmake

I am using openCV 2.4.6.1 in Qt 5.2 on OSX. Everything is fine but when I try to use the cv::CascadeClassifier, a linking error occurs show me that this symbol is not defined for architecture x86_64. Any idea for solving this? Thanks.

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = camera

QT += multimedia multimediawidgets

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include \

LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib \
     -lopencv_core \
     -lopencv_imgproc \
     -lopencv_features2d \
     -lopencv_highgui

HEADERS = \
    camera.h \
    imagesettings.h \
    videosettings.h \


SOURCES = \
    main.cpp \
    camera.cpp \
    imagesettings.cpp \
    videosettings.cpp \

FORMS += \
    camera.ui \
    videosettings.ui \
    imagesettings.ui

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/multimediawidgets/camera
INSTALLS += target

QT+=widgets
```

Comment: Can you show your project file?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Hi, I add it to the question.

Comment: Actually there was same error for my friend using cv::imread(). I guess some functions in OpenCV leads to the error

Comment: Could you please also paste the offending code?

Comment: I figure that out just now. The cv::CascadeClassifier locates in objdetect.hpp in OpenCV so I need to add -lopencv_objdetect in .pro. Thanks @LaszloPapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extend the `LIBS` variable in your project file as follows because the `cv:CascadeClassifier` can be found in that library:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib \
    -lopencv_core \
    -lopencv_imgproc \
    -lopencv_features2d \
    -lopencv_highgui \
    -lopencv_objdetect # This is the addition
```

Comment: I thought it complicated. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

- In the Build Settings tab for your project, scroll down to "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1 - Language"
- Set the setting "C++ Language Dialect" to "C++11 [-std=c++11]"
- Set the setting "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++ (LLVM standard C++ library with C++11 support)"

From:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/4655/link-error-for-only-cascadeclassifier-under-243/