# OpenCV Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: lineDescriptor

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, linker, linker-errors

I built OpenCV from source along with *opencv_contrib* as well.

For some reason all my attempts to access the classes in [`lineDescriptor`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d51/namespacecv_1_1line__descriptor.html) lead to a linker error.

All of these declarations throw a linker error

```
BinaryDescriptor bsd = BinaryDescriptor();
Ptr<BinaryDescriptor> bsd1 = BinaryDescriptor::createBinaryDescriptor();
Ptr<LSDDetector> lsd1 = LSDDetector::createLSDDetector();
```

I fully understand what the error means but I don't know why it is thrown in the first place.

I've looked around and tried different solutions; [changing the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027103/4962554), [verified linker flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595769/4962554) and [linked my libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36113293/4962554), but the error was still getting thrown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace line_descriptor;

void detectLines(Mat& original, Mat grey)
{
    Ptr<LineSegmentDetector> lsd = createLineSegmentDetector(2);

    vector<Vec4f> lines;

    lsd->detect(grey, lines);

    cout << "Detected " << lines.size() << endl;

    lsd->drawSegments(original, lines);

    // Linker problems galore
//  BinaryDescriptor bsd = BinaryDescriptor();
//  Ptr<BinaryDescriptor> bsd1 = BinaryDescriptor::createBinaryDescriptor();
//  Ptr<LSDDetector> lsd1 = LSDDetector::createLSDDetector();

}
```

These are my current linker flags

```
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab
```

I personally feel like it has something to do with my flags but I am not sure of the flag that corresponds to the `lineDescriptor`. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you build with `opencv_contrib`? From OpenCV 3.0 and forward, modules were split into `opencv` and `opencv_contrib` and `line_detector` is [from `opencv_contrib`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/line_descriptor/include/opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp). Have you verified if the `line_descriptor.hpp` file exists in your library path?

Comment: Yes to all of your questions.. Even from Xcode I'm able to locate the header file and see the class definitions.

Comment: I don't think it would affect it but have you tried the `<>` include as opposed to the `""` include (i.e. `#include <opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp>`)? Edit: according to the [README on `opencv_contrib`'s GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) you'll need to include the linker flags for each specific module, e.g., `-lopencv_line_descriptor`.

Comment: DUDE!!!! THANK U SOOOOO SOOOOO MUCH!!!! PLEASE ADD THAT AS AN ANSWER SO I MAY GET U TO 1K REP..Sorry for the caps :)

Comment: No problem, wanted to wait to see if it fixed your issue before adding it as an answer. I did now. And now I'm at 2^10 which is way cooler.

Comment: Hahahaha..Nice one. So I checked your profile and saw that computer vision is your specialty and I needed some ideas on a current problem I'm facing. Would u mind linking up; Skype or something, sometime this weekend and talk it over? I just need a secondary eye on how to solve the problem. Nothing code related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146814/discussion-between-alexander-reynolds-and-eshirima).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [README on `opencv_contrib`'s GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib):

> to run, linker flags to contrib modules will need to be added to use them in your code/IDE. For example to use the aruco module, "-lopencv_aruco" flag will be added.

So you need to simply link the `contrib` module `line_descriptor` with the flag

```
-lopencv_line_descriptor
```

Here's a [thorough answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985713/opencv-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error?noredirect=1&lq=1) which goes over linking all libraries at once during the install step.